# Can't see the error code in the error object

Tags: error

This is my code

```
var sourceSecretKey = 'REDACTED';

var sourceKeypair = StellarSdk.Keypair.fromSecret(sourceSecretKey);
var sourcePublicKey = sourceKeypair.publicKey();


var server = new StellarSdk.Server('https://horizon.stellar.org');
StellarSdk.Network.usePublicNetwork();

server.loadAccount(sourcePublicKey)
    .then(function(account) {            
    var transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(account, {                
        fee: StellarSdk.BASE_FEE        
    })
        // Add a manageOffer operation
        .addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.manageBuyOffer({
        selling: new StellarSdk.Asset.native(),
        buying: new StellarSdk.Asset('ABC', 'GDFBWP6GYJE7PMA4HVLLSPG6346Z67XAME7C2WJIUIA5HGJEJWFWIBPI'),
        amount: '1000000000',
        price: '15.6250000',
        offerId: '0'
        }))
        .addMemo(StellarSdk.Memo.text('Hello'))
        .setTimeout(180)
        .build();

    transaction.sign(sourceKeypair);

     console.log(transaction.toEnvelope().toXDR('base64'));    

    server.submitTransaction(transaction)
        .then(function(transactionResult) {

         console.log(JSON.stringify(transactionResult, null, 2));
         console.log('\nSuccess! View the transaction at: ');
         console.log(transactionResult._links.transaction.href);

        })
        .catch(function(err) {
         console.log('An error has occured:');
         console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, ' '));                                                                            

        });
    })
    .catch(function(e) {
     console.error(e);

    });
```

The stringified error prints merely the following:

```
{
 "message": "Request failed with status code 400",
 "name": "Error",
 "stack": "Error: Request failed with status code 400\n    at createError (http://127.0.0.1:5500/bower_components/stellar-sdk/stellar-sdk.js:27374:15)\n    at settle (http://127.0.0.1:5500/bower_components/stellar-sdk/stellar-sdk.js:46113:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (http://127.0.0.1:5500/bower_components/stellar-sdk/stellar-sdk.js:27236:7)",
 "config": {
  "url": "https://horizon.stellar.org/transactions",
  "method": "post",
  "data": "tx=AAAAAJ2XxPOBZhImQhYvufkgoiaUvlcAA3oYpZpxw4uO%2F3GeAAAAZAGEyw0AAATMAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAF2JMHkAAAABAAAADkNhcnJpZWQgb3V0IG9uAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAMAAAAAAAAAAVVTRAAAAAAA6KYahh5gr2D4B3PgY0blxyy%2BWdyt2jdgjVjvQlEdn9wAAAEcW7%2BrgAAKCWsAmJaAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAY7%2FcZ4AAABAlRB9uf3I2heyWIMNwVp6VWobugg%2B%2FC70y9%2Fplzf%2FCH0orSMapSHVhhYS%2FE78e9Hc2vDw84hfyMQrwLeZ1%2BVVDA%3D%3D",
  "headers": {
   "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
   "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
   "X-Client-Name": "js-stellar-sdk",
   "X-Client-Version": "2.0.1"
  },
  "transformRequest": [
   null
  ],
  "transformResponse": [
   null
  ],
  "timeout": 60000,
  "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
  "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
  "maxContentLength": -1
 }
}
```

The error occurs after submitting the transaction. I would like to see the extras field of the error in order to specifically identify what caused the error. More info at https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/errors/transaction-failed.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altough I don't see a e.response property in your output and I'm not up to date with the latest js-sdk, I think it should still be e.response.data.extras

````
try {
  await server.submitTransaction(...)
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.response.data.extras);
}```
````