# How do I add a trust line to a new account

Tags: stellar-sdk, accounts

The following code creates an account, except for the part where I try to add a trust line to an asset. It returns a code 400. What am I writing incorrectly regarding the add trust operation?

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const StellarSdk = require('stellar-sdk');
StellarSdk.Network.useTestNetwork();
var server = new StellarSdk.Server('https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org');

const source = StellarSdk.Keypair.fromSecret('SK0x0...')
const counterAsset = new StellarSdk.Asset('XAG', 'PK0x0...')

app.get("/wallet", (req, res) => {

  const keyPair = StellarSdk.Keypair.random();

  console.log(keyPair.publicKey())
  console.log(keyPair.secret())

  server.accounts()
  .accountId(source.publicKey())
  .call()
  .then(({ sequence }) => {
    const account = new StellarSdk.Account(source.publicKey(), sequence)

    const builder = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(account, {
      fee: 300
    })
      builder.addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.createAccount({
        destination: keyPair.publicKey(),
        startingBalance: '3.4'
      }))
```

***THIS CHANGE TRUST OPERATION CAUSES REQUEST TO FAIL.

```
      builder.addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.changeTrust({ 
        asset: counterAsset,
        amount: '1000000000000',
        source: keyPair.publicKey()
    }))

      const transaction = builder.build()
      transaction.sign(source)
    return server.submitTransaction(transaction)
  })

  .then(results => {
    console.log('Transaction', results._links.transaction.href)
    console.log('success')
          res.send({
            publicKey: keyPair.publicKey(),
            secretKey: keyPair.secret(),
          })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('error', err);
  })

})

app.listen(3003, () => {
  console.log('Server is up and running on port 3003')
})
```

I am getting a bad request error as follows:

```
error { Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (/Users/Hello/Desktop/Projects/exchangeServer/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/Users/Hello/Desktop/Projects/exchangeServer/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:18:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/Users/Hello/Desktop/Projects/exchangeServer/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:201:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1129:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  config:
   { adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
     transformRequest: { '0': [Function: transformRequest] },
     transformResponse: { '0': [Function: transformResponse] },
     timeout: 60000,
     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
     maxContentLength: -1,
     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
     headers:
      { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'User-Agent': 'axios/0.18.0',
        'Content-Length': 423 },
     method: 'post',
     url: 'https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/transactions',
     data:
      'tx=AAAAAHiP6SBnr%2Bbs42ylxwXgQIS8ho0DW7JmOe91vOoBCYSbAAACWAAA9%2BoAAAC1AAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIGnU6XXtq40HilhyeegzAmJYKEh7wISVMx7QzyltaWcAAAAAAgbMgAAAAAEAAAAAIGnU6XXtq40HilhyeegzAmJYKEh7wISVMx7QzyltaWcAAAAGAAAAAVhBRwAAAAAAz8%2FKnYpsj5whk1w6te4Zz7avOTzHNlgEfnJDgGER4sJ%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwAAAAAAAAABAQmEmwAAAECMNzY%2BA1UK%2FFkBVN9%2FnD8DyA5IpLL4xAVbsq%2BqrcNSa%2FCyB6Rl5N57XtaAy3KMFc1BU5SDCNewdtYwhLVJpGYH' },
  request:
   ClientRequest {
     _events:
      [Object: null prototype] {
        socket: [Function],
        abort: [Function],
        aborted: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        timeout: [Function],
        prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish] },
     _eventsCount: 6,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     output: [],
     outputEncodings: [],
     outputCallbacks: [],
     outputSize: 0,
     writable: true,
     _last: true,
     chunkedEncoding: false,
     shouldKeepAlive: false,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
     sendDate: false,
     _removedConnection: false,
     _removedContLen: false,
     _removedTE: false,
     _contentLength: null,
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: true,
     _headerSent: true,
     socket:
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: false,
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 8,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [TLSWrap],
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'horizon-testnet.stellar.org',
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: true,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: [TLSWrap],
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 208,
        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
        [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
        [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object] },
     connection:
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: false,
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 8,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [TLSWrap],
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'horizon-testnet.stellar.org',
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: true,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: [TLSWrap],
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 208,
        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
        [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
        [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object] },
     _header:
      'POST /transactions HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.18.0\r\nContent-Length: 423\r\nHost: horizon-testnet.stellar.org\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
     _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
     agent:
      Agent {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        defaultPort: 443,
        protocol: 'https:',
        options: [Object],
        requests: {},
        sockets: [Object],
        freeSockets: {},
        keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
        keepAlive: false,
        maxSockets: Infinity,
        maxFreeSockets: 256,
        maxCachedSessions: 100,
        _sessionCache: [Object] },
     socketPath: undefined,
     timeout: undefined,
     method: 'POST',
     path: '/transactions',
     _ended: true,
     res:
      IncomingMessage {
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: false,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 3,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        socket: [TLSSocket],
        connection: [TLSSocket],
        httpVersionMajor: 1,
        httpVersionMinor: 1,
        httpVersion: '1.1',
        complete: true,
        headers: [Object],
        rawHeaders: [Array],
        trailers: {},
        rawTrailers: [],
        aborted: false,
        upgrade: false,
        url: '',
        method: null,
        statusCode: 400,
        statusMessage: 'Bad Request',
        client: [TLSSocket],
        _consuming: false,
        _dumped: false,
        req: [Circular],
        responseUrl: 'https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/transactions',
        redirects: [] },
     aborted: undefined,
     timeoutCb: null,
     upgradeOrConnect: false,
     parser: null,
     maxHeadersCount: null,
     _redirectable:
      Writable {
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _options: [Object],
        _redirectCount: 0,
        _redirects: [],
        _requestBodyLength: 423,
        _requestBodyBuffers: [],
        _onNativeResponse: [Function],
        _currentRequest: [Circular],
        _currentUrl: 'https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/transactions' },
     [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
     [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]:
      [Object: null prototype] {
        accept: [Array],
        'content-type': [Array],
        'user-agent': [Array],
        'content-length': [Array],
        host: [Array] } },
```

And lastly, how can I handle the error, so the request isn't sent over and over? Regards

Answer (score 1):

Since changeTrust affects your newly created account, `source` is not allowed to do  changeTrust operations on behalf of `keyPair`. However `keyPair` may allow it by co-signing the transaction => adding `transaction.sign(keyPair)` should do the trick.

Besides you can get more meaningful errors => [Can't see the error code in the error object](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/2787/cant-see-the-error-code-in-the-error-object/2794#2794)

Comment: Thank you. I was signing with the wrong secret key.